# Temporarily disable SCM polling on Jenkins Server in System Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, version-control

We have a Jenkins server which is running somewhere between 20 and 30 jobs.

Since the build process is reasonably complex we're broken the actual build down into 1 sub-builds, some of which can run concurrently, others have to follow previous build steps. As a result we've grouped each of the build steps into 3 groups, which block while the builds are in pogress.

For example:

```
Main Build : GroupA  : Builds A1, A2 & A3

           : GroupB  : Builds B1, B2 & B3

           : GroupC  : Builds C1, C2, C3, C4, C5 & C6

           : GroupD  : HW_Tests T1, T2, T3, T4 & T5


Builds B1, B2 & B3 rely on the output from A1, A2, A3 etc
```

Since there are builds and tests running pretty much 24/7, I am finding it difficult to schedule a restart of the Jenkins Master. Choosing "Prepare for shutdown" will mean new jobs are queued, but it will invariably block a running job since, to use my example above, if GroupB is active, builds C1, C2, etc will be queued also, and the Main Build will be blocked.

As a work around, I would like to disable the SCM polling on the server until all running jobs have finished. This will prevent new jobs from triggering but also allow the running jobs to finish. I can then restart Jenkins and , re-enable SCM polling, allowing normal service to resume.

The SCM we are using is Perforce.

I have not been able to find anywhere which suggests the above is possible, however, I am sure it must be feasible in System Groovy ... just not sure how. Does anyone here have any ideas please?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could **disable only those jobs which have an SCM polling trigger**. This groovy script will do that:

```
Hudson.instance.items.each { job ->
  if ( job.getTrigger(  hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger ) != null ) {
    println "will disable job ${job.name}"
    job.disable()
  }
}
```

Re-enabling the jobs will be left as an exercise : )

Comment: Thanks @alex-o I think this is going to have to be the way to do it, since there doesn't appear to be a system wide method is suspending SCM Polling for a period of time. It's the headache of "re-enabling" I was trying to avoid.

The wat forward I think will be to turn off SCM polling, update the job's description with some 'marker text', and look for that text when re-enabling after the restart. - I'll post an update with example ceode when done.

Comment: Yes, there is no global setting that disables polling. Regarding headache, you mean the headache from re-enabling jobs that were disabled already before you ran the above script?

Comment: precisely ... (I pressed Enter rather than <shift>-Enter) - the workaround is the above I think.

Comment: Yes, that would be a workaround. There's other option as well, though: instead of _disabling_ the job, you could remove (and re-create) the polling trigger, or you could wipe (and re-define) the polling schedule.

Comment: Ah, yes ... I intend to disable "SCM Polling" rather than disabling the job itself.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins 2.204.1 +  version of using the groovy script console to disable all jobs with an SCM trigger:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each{ job -> 
    if ( job.getSCMTrigger() != null ) {
        println "will disable job ${job.name}"
        job.setDisabled(true)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following Groovy script to comment out SCM Polling:

```
// WARNING: Use on your own risk! Without any warranty!
import hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger
import hudson.triggers.TriggerDescriptor

// from: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12785
TriggerDescriptor SCM_TRIGGER_DESCRIPTOR = Hudson.instance.getDescriptorOrDie(SCMTrigger.class)
assert SCM_TRIGGER_DESCRIPTOR != null;

MAGIC = "#MAGIC# "

// comment out SCM Trigger
def disable_scmpoll_trigger(trig){ 
  if ( !trig.spec.startsWith(MAGIC) ){
    return new SCMTrigger(MAGIC + trig.spec)
  }
  return null  
}

// enable commented out SCM Trigger
def enable_scmpoll_trigger(trig){ 
  if ( trig.spec.startsWith(MAGIC) ){
    return new SCMTrigger(trig.spec.substring(MAGIC.length()))
  }
  return null  
}

Hudson.instance.items.each {
  job -> 
  //println("Checking job ${job.name} of type ${job.getClass().getName()} ...")

  // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39100687
  def trig = job.getTrigger( hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger )
  if ( trig == null ) return
  println("Job ${job.name} has SCMTrigger: '${trig.spec}'")

  SCMTrigger newTrig = disable_scmpoll_trigger(trig)
  // SCMTrigger newTrig = enable_scmpoll_trigger(trig)

  if (newTrig != null ){
    newTrig.ignorePostCommitHooks = trig.ignorePostCommitHooks
    newTrig.job = job
    println("Updating SCMTrigger '${trig.spec}' -> '${newTrig.spec}' for job: ${job.name}")
    job.removeTrigger(SCM_TRIGGER_DESCRIPTOR)
    job.addTrigger(newTrig)
    job.save()
  }    
}
return ''
```

To enable SCM polling again just change these two lines

```
  //SCMTrigger newTrig = disable_scmpoll_trigger(trig)
  SCMTrigger newTrig = enable_scmpoll_trigger(trig)
```

Tested on Jenkins ver. 2.121.3

Known limitations:

- supports single line "Schedule"  (`spec` property) only

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is one or 2 builds that are configured to do SCM polling, you can go into the configuration of each build and uncheck the box. It is that simple :)
2. If you are using jenkins job builder, it should be even easier to change the configuration of several jobs at a time.
3. If you using slaves or even on master, SCM polling is dependent on JAVA ? remove JAVA from the machine temporarily from the location where it is configured in master jenkins ;) The polling will fail :P This is a stupid hack ;)

I hope that helps !! ?